# `jax.jit` not improving in place update performance for large arrays?

Tags: numpy, jit, jax

I am trying to apply a number of in place updates to a 2D matrix.

It appears that using `jit` to the in place update does not have any effect in computation time (which is many orders of magnitude longer than the equivalent `numpy` implementation).

Here is code that demonstrates my problem and research.

```
node_count = 10000

# NUMPY IMPLEMENTATION
b = onp.zeros([node_count,node_count])
print("`numpy` in place update.")
%timeit b[1,1] = 1.
# 86.9 ns ± 1.42 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)

# JAX IN PLACE IMPLEMENTATION
a = np.zeros([node_count,node_count])
print("`jax.np` in place update.")
%timeit a.at[1,1].set(1.)
# 112 ms ± 14.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


## TEST JIT IMPLEMENTATION
def update(mat, index, val):
    return mat.at[tuple(index)].set(val)
update_jit = jit(update)

# Run once for trace.
update_jit(a, [1,1], 1.).block_until_ready()

print("`jax.np` jit in place update.")
%timeit update_jit(a, [1,1],1.).block_until_ready()
# 99.6 ms ± 358 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with inlining of inplace updates. This has to do with the fact that, unless otherwise requested, a JIT-compiled function will always return its result in a new, distinct buffer. The only exception to this is if you use [buffer donation](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#buffer-donation) to explicitly mark that the input buffer can be re-used in the output:

```py
update_jit = jit(update, donate_argnums=[0])
```

Note, however, that buffer donation is currently only available on GPU and TPU runtimes.

You'll not be able to use `%timeit` in this case, because the donated input buffer is no longer available for use after the first iteration, but you can confirm via `%time` that this improves the computation speed:

```py
# Following is run on a Colab T4 GPU runtime

update_jit = jit(update)
_ = update_jit(b, [1,1], 1.)
%time _ = update_jit(b, [1,1], 1.).block_until_ready()
# CPU times: user 607 µs, sys: 112 µs, total: 719 µs
# Wall time: 5.89 ms

update_jit_donate = jit(update, donate_argnums=[0])
b = update_jit_donate(b, [1,1], 1.)
%time _ = update_jit_donate(b, [1,1], 1.).block_until_ready()
# CPU times: user 467 µs, sys: 86 µs, total: 553 µs
# Wall time: 332 µs
```

The buffer donation version is still quite a bit slower than the NumPy version, but this is expected for the reasons discussed at [FAQ: Is JAX Faster Than Numpy?](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#is-jax-faster-than-numpy).

I suspect you're performing these micro-benchmarks to assure yourself that the compiler performs updates in-place within a JIT-compiled sequence of operations rather than making internal copies, as is mentioned in [Sharp Bits: Array Updates](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#array-updates-x-at-idx-set-y). If so, you can confirm this by other means; for example:

```py
@jit
def sum(x):
  return x.sum()

@jit
def update_and_sum(x):
  return x.at[0, 0].set(1).sum()

_ = sum(b)
%timeit sum(b).block_until_ready()
# 1.66 ms ± 7.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

_ = update_and_sum(b)
%timeit update_and_sum(b).block_until_ready()
# 1.66 ms ± 20.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The identical timings here show that the update operation is being performed in-place rather than causing the input buffer to be copied.

Answer (score -1):

The JIT version is slower because it does not operate in-place as opposed to the Numpy version: it creates a copy of the array and then modify the items. You can see that by growing the array: the execution time is proportional to the size of the array. You can also check the array `a` is left unmodified after the call to `set`. You can also see that the time of `b.fill(42.0)` is very close to the speed of the JAX function (but strangely not `b.copy()`). The out-of-place version is significantly slower because the RAM is slow and it takes a lot of time to operate on the whole array than just setting 1 value.

Comment: This answer is misleading: the buffer copy does not come from an out-of-place update, but rather from the JIT function boundary.

Comment: @jakevdp No, I didn't said that the update was out-of-place but the whole "JIT version" and did not mention the source causing that. As you said, "a JIT-compiled function will always return its result in a new, distinct buffer" so it is an out-of-place operation since the input buffer is not modified and a newly modified array is returned. So which exact part is supposed to be misleading to you?